# Passing additional params to GET_ONE

Tags: reactjs, aws-amplify, react-admin

I am using React admin with Amplify. I have written my own custom data provider for fetching data as I didn't find any data providers that was compatible with Appsync Graphql. So now I have a Graphql model as such

```
type Task @model @key(fields:["id","timestamp"]){
  id: ID!
  user: User @connection(name: "MyUserTask")
  status: Status
  timestamp: AWSDateTime!
}
```

Here the primary key is `id` and the sort key is `timestamp`. I am able to get all of the `Task` in either ascending or descending order based on the timestamp but however I am not able to get a single `Task` as `GET_ONE` in data provider only gets the `id` as a param but to get one `Task` I need to provide both the `id` and `timestamp`. So how can I pass the timestamp along with the id when Show button is pressed.

PS: I have both the `id` and `timestamp` when am at the list view.